# Pass dynamic object in onclick - JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to pass a dynamic object in `onclick` jQuery. Please check the below snippet in which I am getting object `product` value as `undefined`. Can someone help me on how to pass and receive object value in JavaScript/jQuery?

```js
var hpc = "";

function handleProductsClick(e, product) {
  debugger;
  alert(product && JSON.stringify(product));
}

function buildProducts(products) {
  var bp = '';
  hpc = handleProductsClick.bind(products[i]);
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    bp += '<li onclick="hpc(event)">' + products[i].value + '</li>';
  }
  $("#products").html(bp);
}

function getProductsFromApi() {
  var products = [{
      key: 1,
      value: "Apple"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: "Android"
    }
  ];
  buildProducts(products);
}

getProductsFromApi();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="products"></ul>
```

Comment: `hpc = handleProductsClick.bind(products[i]);` in this line `i` is undefined

Comment: Do you want to alert the `id` when you click on 'li' ??

Comment: What dynamic object are you trying to pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try attaching the listener properly using event listeners in Javascript rather than inline HTML attributes (which is as bad as `eval`). Also, when you use `bind`, the first argument is the `this` value provided to the function; the *second* argument to `.bind` corresponds to the first argument in the other function.

```js
function handleProductsClick(product) {
  console.log(product && JSON.stringify(product));
}

function buildProducts(products) {
  products.forEach(product => {
    const li = $('<li>' + product.value + '</li>');
    li.on('click', handleProductsClick.bind(null, product));
    $("#products").append(li)
  });
}

function getProductsFromApi() {
  var products = [{
      key: 1,
      value: "Apple"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: "Android"
    }
  ];
  buildProducts(products);
}

getProductsFromApi();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="products"></ul>
```

Comment: Is there a way we can use `html()` instead of `append()`?

Comment: No, because `html` only sets an HTML string, not an actual element. (strings can't have listeners attached to them; elements can.) Definitely use `append`.

Comment: Ok. But is there any performance issue if I use `append` instead of `html`?

Comment: No performance issue, performance is almost never something worth worrying about anyway

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to avoid the use of inline `onclick`, and try to attach the event to the `li` or to common classes, the n use `data-* attributes` to pass the information you want :

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.my_item', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('product'));
  });
});

function buildProducts(products) {
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    $("#products").append("<li class='my_item' data-product='" + JSON.stringify(products[i]) + "'>" + products[i].value + "</li>");
  }
}

function getProductsFromApi() {
  var products = [{
      key: 1,
      value: "Apple"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: "Android"
    }
  ];

  buildProducts(products);
}

getProductsFromApi();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="products"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var hpc = "";

function handleProductsClick(e, product) {
  debugger;
  alert(product && JSON.stringify(product));
}

function buildProducts(products) {
  var bp = '';
  hpc = handleProductsClick.bind(products[i]);
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    bp += '<li onclick="hpc(event)">' + products[i].value + '</li>';
  }
  $("#products").html(bp);
}

function getProductsFromApi() {
  var products = [{
      key: 1,
      value: "Apple"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: "Android"
    }
  ];
  buildProducts(products);
}

getProductsFromApi();
```